# Firebase realtime database retrieve null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want retrieve a video url from Firebase realtime database, but in mine object the url is null.

This is my database:

[image]

The video is located in the Firebase Storage.
If I search the URL, Google finds it

This is my code:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    listaEsercizi.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String nome = snapshot.getValue(Esercizio.class).getNome();
        String video = snapshot.getValue(Esercizio.class).getVideoURI().toString();
        listaEsercizi.add(new Esercizio(video, nome));
    }
```

So, the string in "nome" is "Parallele", but the string in "video" is null.

From the debug I realized that in "getVideoUri().toString()" exist the URL, but not is assigned in "video".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming for your `Video` is not match as the database.

Change from:

```
private String videoURI;
//Here is video getset
```

To:

```
private String video;
//Here is video getset
```

And then, you can call them like this:

```
 String nome = snapshot.getValue(Esercizio.class).getNome();
 String video = snapshot.getValue(Esercizio.class).getVideo();
 listaEsercizi.add(new Esercizio(video, nome));
```

Comment: Oh it work. I don't know why, but it work.

Comment: @BryanSanchez it is working because. You have to match your variable with your database. at your database, you use `video` but at your model class you used `videoURI`. That's why it was not working.